# Is the Nativescript HTTP module secure?

Tags: http, https, nativescript, httpmodule

I make POST requests with the Nativescript HTTP module on my website that has an HTTPS address. Is it secure or the data is transmitted in clear? Thanking you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple HTTPS calls can be still intercepted. So if your data is very much sensitive, for more secured connection you have to use SSL pinning thats supported by nativescript-https plug-in.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The data sent by the Nativescript HTTP module to the HTTPS website is encrypted, but it can be intercepted. Did I understand?

Comment: Honestly speaking there is nothing called unbreakable. In general there are always levels of security, HTTPS is better than HTTP, SSL pinning is even more secured. If you want to take it to next level, then I often see people encrypt their request and response with crypto.

Comment: Thank you for your answers that helped me a lot.